# Ozzie workflow example

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop-streaming, oozie

I'm having trouble understanding Oozie. I've got it running but the documentation and examples I have found are not clear. Can anyone help me with an example?

I have 4 or 5 hadoop streaming jobs, for each I want to delete any existing output directory and logs, e.g.

`hadoop fs -rm -r /user/vm/video-output /tmp/logs/vm/logs/`

run the job, e.g.

```
hadoop jar ~/run/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -files videoapp 
-cacheArchive hdfs://localhost:54310/user/vm/input/video/video.tar.gz#video 
-cacheFile hdfs://localhost:54310/user/vm/vqatsAx#vqatsAx 
-cacheFile hdfs://localhost:54310/user/vm/ffmpeg#ffmpeg 
-input /user/vm/input/video -output /user/vm/video-output 
-mapper videoapp/video.py -cmdenv VIDEO_DIR=video
```

then when that is finished (how do i check this: a part-r-0000 is created?), run the next one. These jobs will be reading from and writing to HBase. I'd just like a basic outline and a few pointers [this sort of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499526/simple-oozie-example-of-hive-query). TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

For deleting HDFS directories or logs you can use Oozie HDFS action. The oozie documentation and example for this is here [oozie HDFS action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action). Or the example is given below. You can configure as many various actions you need in the workflow.xml.

```
<workflow-app name="sample-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    ...
    <action name="hdfscommands">
         <fs>
            <delete path='hdfs://foo:9000/usr/tucu/temp-data'/>
            <mkdir path='archives/${wf:id()}'/>
            <move source='${jobInput}' target='archives/${wf:id()}/processed-input'/>
            <chmod path='${jobOutput}' permissions='-rwxrw-rw-' dir-files='true'/>
        </fs>
        <ok to="myotherjob"/>
        <error to="errorcleanup"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```